# C# DotNet 6.0 Library for Linux or Raspberry Pi4 getting the error "UsbDevice' does not contain a definition for 'OpenUsbDevice'"

Tags: c#, linux, .net-6.0, raspberry-pi4, libusb

I have a small device currently that can be communicated with windows platform with Dot Net C# (HID) based application. I wanted it to communicate with Linux or Raspberry Pi4 device using usb. I have created the small application and using the “**LibUsbDotNet**” library (Cross Platform). But my application fails to OpenUsbDevice.

I have searched a lot the solution, but I did not get any success. Is there any suitable Dot Net 6.0 based USB library for Linux platform.

Getting the error as
error CS0117: **'UsbDevice' does not contain a definition for 'OpenUsbDevice'**

```
using System;
    using LibUsbDotNet;
    using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
    using Usb.Net;
    namespace Usb.Net.WindowsSample
    {
        using System;
        using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Find and open the USB device
                UsbDeviceFinder finder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x1234, 0x5678); // Replace with your device's Vendor ID and Product ID
                UsbDevice usbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(finder);
                if (usbDevice == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("USB device not found.");
                    return;
                }
                // Perform operations on the USB device
                // Close the device when done
                usbDevice.Close();
            }
        }
```

Or

```
 UsbDeviceFinder usbDeviceFinder = null;

       if (deviceDefinition.VendorId.HasValue)
       {
           if (deviceDefinition.ProductId.HasValue)
           {
               usbDeviceFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder((int)deviceDefinition.VendorId.Value, (int)deviceDefinition.ProductId.Value);
           }
           else
           {
               usbDeviceFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder((int)deviceDefinition.VendorId.Value);
           }
       }

       var usbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(usbDeviceFinder);
```

Comment: Well, what made you think there *is* an `OpenUsbDevice` method (in the current version)?

Comment: (I *suspect* you want `UsbContext.FindAll(UsbDeviceFinder)` or `UsbContext.Find(UsbDeviceFinder)` and then use `IUsbDevice.Open` to open a specific device...

Comment: Yes I need something like UsbContext. But I can't find the latest Library for it. My main aim to access the device on Raspberry Pi  via USB communication using C# .Net 6.0.